# Get the message object of a message you replied to (Discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How would I get the message object of a message I replied to? E.g. Someone said "Hello, How are you!". And I replied to that message calling the `.good` command, it would print the message (Hello, How are you!)'s message object. I've looked all over discord.py docs but haven't seen a thing mentioning something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `discord.Message.reference` attribute. In your question you'd do something like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def good(ctx):
    # If this message has a reference (meaning it's a reply)
    if ctx.message.reference:
        original = await ctx.fetch_message(id=ctx.message.reference.message_id)
        text = original.content
        print(f"Author said {text}")
```

This is the link to the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.reference